# How to initialize variables for LSTM models in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, tensorflow2.0, initializer

In Tensorflow 1, you can initialize the variables when you define the variable scope such as

```
initer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.5, 0.5, seed=111)

    with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=None, initializer=initer),
```

How do I achieve this in Tensorflow 2 where I am using Keras functional model to build an LSTM model?

`tf.global_variables_initializer()` is not part of tf2. As I understand it, the default in tf2 is `glorot_uniform` initializer. I want to try other initializers available in tf2 but I don't know where/ how to initialize the variables.

I've seen examples where initialization is added to the layer definition itself such as

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')
```

But is this available for LSTM layer as well?

Also if we take this approach, does it mean we only add the kernel initializer to the first layer of the network?

Comment: Yes it is available. The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM?version=stable) explain it well. And you can have any number of LSTM layers and you can have different initializers for different layers. Using initializer for one layer doesn't mean it's gonna be used for the others.

Comment: It's good to know that initializer defined during the first layer is used and others are ignored. Thanks!